# Is it possible for a class object to keep a static pointer to itself?

Tags: c++, templates

I know this sounds like a weird thing to want, but I guess I have my reasons. I can do:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Shark
{
    template <auto* static_ptr_to_self>
    void whatIsMyAddress() {
        std::cout << std::string("My address is ") + std::to_string((uintptr_t)static_ptr_to_self);
    }
};

Shark shark;

int main()
{
    
    shark.whatIsMyAddress<&shark>();


    return 0;

}
```

But is there a way to achieve something like this without passing in the pointer to the function? For example can the object itself hold a pointer, resolved at compile-time, not a runtime pointer, to itself? My instinct is no because when the object is created it hasn't been declared yet. But is there some way to achieve this? If there isn't through passing the pointer as a template argument then is there a way with a constexpr member pointer?

Edit: Just to explain my question better:

```
struct ResourceMngr
{
    void IveBeenCopied(const Handle& handle);
    
    int referenceCountTracker[256];
};


struct Handle
{
    int ID;
    Handle(const Handle& other) { dynamicPtrToManager->IveBeenCopied(*this); }
    ResourceMngr* dynamicPtrToManager;
};


void ResourceMngr::IveBeenCopied(const Handle& handle) 
{ 
    ++referenceCountTracker[handle.ID]; 
}
```

So each handle has a pointer to let whatever is managing the resource know of 'stuff'. So now I can get rid of the pointer in handle, which has the effect of eliminating the pointer lookup (because it's constexpr) and also eliminating a pointer from each handle, by doing this:

```
    struct ResourceMngr
    {
        
        void IveBeenCopied(const auto& handle);
        
        int referenceCountTracker[256];
    };
    
    template <auto* static_ptr_to_manager>
    struct Handle
    {
        int ID;
        Handle() {}
        Handle(const Handle& other) { static_ptr_to_manager->IveBeenCopied(*this); }
        //ResourceMngr* dynamicPtrToManager; // No longer needed
    };
    
    
    void ResourceMngr::IveBeenCopied(const auto& handle) { ++referenceCountTracker[handle.ID]; }
    
    ResourceMngr bufferManager;
    
    
    int main()
    {
        Handle<&bufferManager> handle1;
        Handle<&bufferManager> handle2 = handle1; 
    // No pointer members in each handle, 
    // no runtime lookup of pointers
    }
```

And I can get a handle from a resource manager like:

```
template <auto* static_ptr_to_manager>
struct Handle
{
    int ID;
    Handle() {}
    Handle(const Handle& other) { 
        //static_ptr_to_manager->IveBeenCopied(*this); 
    }
};

struct ResourceMngr
{
    template <auto* static_ptr_to_self_type>
    Handle<static_ptr_to_self_type> getHandleToAResourceOrObject()
    {
        return Handle<static_ptr_to_self_type>();
    }
};

ResourceMngr bufferManager;


int main()
{
    Handle<&bufferManager> handle = bufferManager.getHandleToAResourceOrObject<&bufferManager>();
        // Here I have to specify in the function call 
//which manager I'm referring to. 
        // The bufferManager couldn't use the this pointer as 
//it's not constexpr and can't be used      
// in template arguments
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you want a singleton or at least if you do this you will be limited to a single instance of your class.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  Why do you need the address at compile time?  Why doesn't `this` (literally the address of the object) work for you?

Comment: As written, this doesn't make sense. You can have several `Shark` instances, they all share the same static fields, yet you want each one of them to point to a different thing.

Comment: @al3c Each Shark object would have a pointer to itself, but instead of a member pointer resolved at runtime as in a member Shark* self; or this pointer, it would be a compile-time static pointer that could be used in template non-type arguments.

Comment: In C++, all non-static member functions of `struct` or `class` types have access to the `this` pointer, which points at the current instance.   For example, given a call `shark.foo()`, the function `Shark::foo()` has access to `this`, which will be equivalent (within context of the caller) to `&shark`.   This is true regardless of whether the member function is templated or not.   For example,  (within the `struct` definition of `Shark`)  `void PrintMyAddress() {std::cout << "My address is " << (void *)this;}`

Comment: @Zebrafish the set of addresses where you will alocate `Shark` objects can't be known at compile time. Just imagine a program that depending on random allocates 1 or 2 `Shark`s

Comment: When you use Shark e.g. as a local variable, the address is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: @NathanOliver I've updated the question with more information. I just wanted to keep it simple but I've added an explanation of what I'm doing.

Comment: @birdfreeyahoo Yes, I know, but as a static object, either global or namespace or class static member, the address is compile-time known and constexpr. I've added to the question what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Zebrafish I'm still unclear on your goals, though, why does `static_ptr_to_manager` need to be a template parameter? Seems you can just pass it the constructor of `Handle` like any other dependency

Comment: @al3c You can pass static_ptr_to_manager in the Handle constructor, but the idea is that the manager has a function called template <typename ... ConstructorArgs> createAndReturnHandle() { /* A Handle<static_ptr_template_arg> needs to be constructed here and returned */ } I can pass in the static_ptr when I call the createAndReturnHandle, but I have variadic ConstructorArgs, so it messes things up a bit.

Comment: @Zebrafish I don't get what major disadvantages you get by just using a regular pointer. This seems just overcomplicated optimization. I mean you could just initialize the Handle with this-pointer